# setting attribute depending on cookie value - good practices, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, request

I have this code to triggger jQuery slideUp some elements when page loads:

```
@if(request()->cookie('pin-toolbox-for-objects') == 1)
    <?php $show_toolbox_objects = ''; ?>
@else
    <?php $show_toolbox_objects = 'data-more-close';?>
@endif


<div {{$show_toolbox_objects}} id="toolbox">

    @include('navs._toolbox_object_buttons')

</div>
```

### to do

Is there any way to improve on this code?

Comment: You can create some hidden div with content, then in jquery check if cookie exists and (when exists) set div to visible

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the issue. I reveal these elements with annimation provided by jQuery's slideUp & slideDown. The issue is how to beautify the code

Answer (score 0):

This would be more elegant:

```
<div <?php (request()->cookie('pin-toolbox-for-objects') == 1)?'test':'data-more-close'?> id="toolbox">
```

but it diesn't work. This one, surprisingly, does:

```
<div @if(request()->cookie('pin-toolbox-for-objects') == 1) data-more-close @endif id="toolbox">
```